# How do I get Realms for Minecraft: PE 0.8.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I get access to Realms on Minecraft PE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get [Minecraft Realms on the Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.net/realms/faq) yet but when Realms is able to be put on PE, yes, you will either have to buy it or be invited by someone.

Answer (score -2):

Someone has to Invite you I suggest inviting them. I hope this helped